Is there any way to know how much time of totality is experienced during a hybrid eclipse in NASA’s 5 Millennium Canon of Solar Eclipses?
I was just looking through NASA’s 5 Millennium Canon of Solar Eclipses. It’s really a fantastic list, having the max time of totality and all. I was trying to figure out what the maximum amount of time spent in totality over 5,000 years an individual could hope to enjoy. Judging based on their data, the maximum amount that could be hoped for was 11,269 minutes and 46 seconds. The problem is that there are 569 hybrid eclipses that are unaccounted for, because you only get one number, the central duration, that combines annularity and totality. I just wanted to know if there is anyway to tell how much of a hybrid eclipse was spent in totality, versus annularity. Is there any way to get this information?

Fred Espenak's more recent (& slightly more accurate) six millennium catalog may help. Eg, https://eclipsewise.com/solar/SEprime/1801-1900/SE1807Nov29Hprime.html says max duration is 01m25.64s. But it's an annular-total-annular hybrid.

You need something that computes the local circumstances.  Many of the various eclipse maps will do that when you select a specific spot.
